# Puppeteer can't click on element after page.waitForTimeout called

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer, telegram-bot

I'm practicing with Telegram bots and puppeteer so I've decided to create a bot to order pizza from a specific website.

Once the bot has taken the order he needs to place the data he took to inputs on the page, here how it looks like:

[image]

These two fields are spans and when puppeteer clicks on the enabled one (left) he gets an input to complete. Then when the first input is done puppeteer has to do the exact same procedure with the second field: click on `<span>` tag, place data in input, etc.

But the thing is that there is a small-time gap between the completion of the first field and activation of the second one. My bot doesn't recognize this gap and clicks on the second field's span instantly (and of course it doesn't work).

Here's a code fragment:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="select2-chosen-2"]', {visible: true})
const [secondSpan] = await page.$x('//*[@id="select2-chosen-2"]')
await secondSpan.click()
```

When I type `node bot` with this fragment I get no errors or warnings. But as I said it takes some time for the second field to activate. I've found a function to make puppeeter stop the execution of my code for a certain time period: `page.waitForTimeout()`.

Here the example of usage in puppeteer's documentation:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.waitForTimeout(1000).then(() => console.log('Waited a second!'));

  await browser.close();
})();
```

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.1.0&show=api-pagewaitfortimeoutmilliseconds

Here's my case:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="select2-chosen-2"]', {visible: true})
const [secondSpan] = await page.$x('//*[@id="select2-chosen-2"]')

page.waitForTimeout(1500)

await secondSpan.click()
```

This code also doesn't show any error, but it also doesn't click on the field. When I add `await` to `page.waitForTimeout()` I get this error:

```
Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot to `await`  your `page.waitForTimeout(1500)` call. I don't know Russian and I'm unable to select an option to enable the `select2-chosen-2` dropdown, but probably the best approach is to poll it being enabled with `page.waitForFunction`, injecting your own `MutationObserver` or `requestAnimationFrame` loop by hand using `evaluate`, or writing a loop in Node space with a short sleep that keeps checking whether it's enabled. If you can explain what input I should give it to move on to the next option box, I can offer an answer.

Comment: As an aside, it seems silly to use XPath for a simple id: `'//*[@id="select2-chosen-2"]'` can be `await page.waitForSelector("#select2-chosen-2"); await page.$("#select2-chosen-2")`. Or just `page.click("#select2-chosen-2")`.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for your answer I'll try to do what you suggested. Speaking about ```await``` and ```page.waitForTimeout```, I've already described this situation in the last paragraph :)

Comment: @ggorlen yeah I know but it doesn't matter for me, just wanted to see how XPAth works

Comment: Gotcha -- I guess I missed that, but not `await`ing it makes no sense so that's not even an option to try. Best case scenario it does nothing, worst case it just throws when you try to take an action on a closed `page` or causes weird behavior due to a race condition. Another thing is, sometimes `click` fails because Puppeteer uses the mouse to do it, but you can bypass it with `page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#select2-chosen-2").click())` which lets you click on elements Puppeteer can't find otherwise.

Comment: @ggorlen oh I'm so sorry I didn't recognize that you asked for possible input to the first field. You can write ```Победителей просп.``` and that will lead you to the field with building numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I needed was to put this code:

```
await page.click('#s2id_home-number-modal')
```

Or using XPath:

```
const [secondSpan] = await page.$x('//*[@id="select2-chosen-2"]')
await secondSpan.click()
```

into `.then()` method, that is called after `page.setTimeout(500)`.
All in all, it looks like this (by the way, I've changed some selectors, but it's not a big deal):

```
await page.waitForTimeout(500).then(async () => {
   await page.click('#s2id_home-number-modal')
})
```